# Jquery Mobile button not responding properly on iphone

Tags: jquery, mobile, styling, beta

I need to display the customer's email and phone numbers in listview and address on the button so that user can tap on to move to the next page. I am getting the json data and adding List items dynamially using javascript and displaying using JQuery Mobile Beta 1. To appy the styling , I am calling the .page() method followed by .listview().

I am facing two problems:

1. In the list of items, when I tap the listitem on iPhone it does nothing. But holding it for a moment, it opens up the options like open, open in safari etc and on clicking on it can see the next page. It is happening for every item. Whether it is a list item, back button or anchor with data-role="button". It is working fine on browser with perfect mouse click. Need help!!
2. I am applying some style on the buttons ( with data-role="button:) to show the address. It shows perfectly on the very first time but if I move to list using back button and then click on item again, it displays the listview items properly styled but buttons as simple links and not buttons with style applied.

Can you please advise why it is behaving like this on iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first problem is concerned, it was the flaw in Jquery mobile Beta 1 which was been fixed in some of the nighly builds and can be downloadable from Jquery mobile forums.

for second, I have added the tags in html and then replace the html in between using jquery.